# find non-paired values on table join Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I am joining on the `emp`. However I am also trying to find when the join pairing doesn't happen.

```
table: emp
+--------------------+
| emp                |
+--------------------+
| 121211             |
| 121212             |
| 121213             |
| 121214             |
+--------------------+

table: empskills
+--------------------+------------------+
| emp            | skill            |
+--------------------+------------------+
| 121211             | 15               |
| 121212             | 15               |
+--------------------+------------------+

SELECT e.emp, es.skill FROM emp e
    JOIN empskills es
    ON es.emp = e.emp;
```

So I am trying to locate the employees that are in the table with the skill they possess along with those that aren't in the table. Those that aren't in the table will just be given a "null" value to the `es.skill` column.

Comment: change JOIN  to LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT e.emp, es.skill 
FROM emp e
LEFT JOIN empskills es ON es.emp = e.emp
WHERE es.skills > 0 
   OR es.skills IS NULL
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Great so what if I want to add a WHERE statement like:
SELECT e.emp, es.skill 
FROM emp e
LEFT JOIN empskills es ON es.emp = e.emp
WHERE es.skills > 0 OR IS NULL;

It doesn't seem to like that concept.

Comment: Or how can I show just the emp from the emp table that don't appear in the empskills table?